# SQL Computed Colums from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im trying to create the derived attribute availability in the item table, in order to do that do i need to create a join?

Availability Checks if todays date is between checkoutDate and returndate.

Here is the ER diagram:

[image]

Comment: @MahmoudGamal SQL Server 2008 and the er diagram is created in creately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use this as a computed column, then I would recommend using a UDF.  In your diagram, you have Availability as a boolean.  SQL Server does not have a boolean data type, so I assume you mean a bit.  This should be pretty close, but you'd need to test it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue
(
    @barcode int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @field bit
     SELECT @field = CASE WHEN GETDATE() 
                BETWEEN L.LastReturnDate AND R.ReturnDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       FROM [Item] I
        JOIN [Load] L ON I.barcode = L.barcode
        JOIN [Return] R ON I.barcode = R.barcode
       WHERE I.barcode = @barcode
      RETURN @field
END
GO
```

And then using that as your computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Item
ADD Availability AS dbo.GetValue(barcode)
```

With that said, this might be better suited for a View.

Comment: ALTER TABLE dbo.Item
ADD Availability AS dbo.GetValue(barcode) Gives me the following error  Msg 2705, Level 16,  State 5, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'availability' in table 'dbo.Item' is specified more than once.

Comment: @Sebastian -- unfortunately you can't alter an existing column -- the error you're receiving is because the above is trying to add a new column.  You'll need to drop and readd that column -- check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372655/how-can-i-alter-this-computed-column-in-sql-server-2008 -- best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to do a join.

I would recommend that you use a view to put together the data from the different tables.

Comment: @Sebastian . .  . Have you tried any queries?  You should include such a query in your question.

Comment: No, I havent tried any queries for this case yet. I'll keep that in mind next time i post a question.