# Alter a function with SCHEMABINDING used as formula for a calculated field with index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a `PERSISTED` and indexed calculated field (`Test`) based on the result of a function (`MyFunctionTest`), eg.:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Foo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Test]  AS ([dbo].[MyFunctionTest]([Foo])) PERSISTED,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

`MyFunctionTest` is:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunctionTest]
(
    @foo int
)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @foo * 2
END
```

If I try to alter the function, SQL server shows the error

> Cannot ALTER 'dbo.MyFunctionTest' it is being referenced by object 'TestTable'.

The only way for alter the function seem create a new one an alter the the table.

I've also tried to remove `WITH SCHEMABINDING`

Comment: Not really a question, more of a rant. Those are the rules - you can't change the function due to the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the column, alter the function, and add the column back:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
    DROP COLUMN [Test];

GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunctionTest]
(
    @foo int
)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @foo * 2
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
    ADD [Test] AS ([dbo].[MyFunctionTest]([Foo])) PERSISTED
```

Creating a new function will also mean you need to drop the column and add it back since [computed columns can't be altered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372655/how-can-i-alter-this-computed-column-in-sql-server-2008).

Comment: `Creating a new function will also mean you need to drop the column and add it back` in sqlserver 2005 i can alter computed column...

Comment: i'm on sql server 2005, i have altered a computed column with a new function

Comment: Official documentation starts at 2008 (the oldest currently supported version soon to be out of extended support) and memory is not what it used to be, so I really didn't know it's possible on 2005 version. You really should consider upgrading your sql server version to at least 2012.

Comment: Maybe it's the ide (sql server management studio) that "drop - alter" in background... upgrading, i would like, but it isn't my company :D