# How can I perform column alteration with persisted and right ()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

I have a table in Sql Server, in which I want to generate alphanumeric sheets. So I'm going to make an alter column but when I execute it, it gives me an error, I don't understand why it happens. Here is the SQL code:

```
  ALTER TABLE [DB_AtencionCliente].[WAPP].[TBL_TRANSFERENCIA_BANCARIA]
  ALTER COLUMN FOLIO AS ([TIPO_TRX] + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST([TRX] AS VARCHAR(9)), 9)) PERSISTED;
```

Comment: What's the error that it gives you?

Comment: @squillman The mistake is: "  Incorrect syntax near '('.  "

Comment: You can't alter a computed column.  You can only drop it and readd it with the new formula.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  Even though the linked question is for SQL Server 2008 it still applies. [How can I alter this computed column in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372655/how-can-i-alter-this-computed-column-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Just an aside.  If by chance you have NULLs, rather than generating a NULL, concat() will treat them as an empty string...    concat([TIPO_TRX],RIGHT(concat('000000000',[TRX]), 9))